# chart js datapoints are not the same numer for all products

Tags: chart.js, primeng, pchart

I have a chartjs that shows one of the line wrongly:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QTXwJ.png)

As you can see the "DIESEL" product has not the same numbers of data points that others product:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nt7Rg.png)

The problem is the datapoint for "DIESEL" not match with the X-Axis labels because it should start on 2022-07-06 and it is starting on 2022-07-06 as the other products.

I have not idea how can I fix it.

Comment: You will need to use object notation: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/general/data-structures.html

Comment: Your x axis appears to be a category axis, the values are just strings without any meaning (you can see that from the fact that intervals of 5 days have the same length as intervals of 1 or 2 days). The first step would be to declare the x scale type as `type: "time"`, (in `options.scales.x`). Then add an adapter library (the most used is [date-fns](https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-adapter-date-fns), and manage the other options see the [docs](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html) and [samples](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/scales/time-line.html)

Comment: To get a useful answer you should consider including your code in your question, stackoverflow is all about questions with code and answers with code. Read the [minimal reproducible example tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for tips on that